# Cannot connect ASP .NET container to mssql container

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have an ASP .NET app in a container that I am trying to connect to a mssql container (running in the same network) but no matter what I change in the connection string, my app still crashes `Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'`.

My docker file looks like this:

```
services:
  dotnet_be:
    build: "./"
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

And my connection string looks like this:

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=db;Database=DeskBooking;User id=sa;Password=Your_password123;Trusted_Connection=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=False;"
```

I am using `db` as server as both services are within the same network and they are accessible via the container name.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not respect password security requirements.

Try this changes:

```yaml
services:
  dotnet_be:
    build: "./"
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - my-network

  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD:1hisIsStrongPwd!!
      ACCEPT_EULA:Y
    networks:
      - my-network
```

```json
"ConnectionString": "Server=db;Database=DeskBooking;User id=sa;Password=1hisIsStrongPwd!!;Trusted_Connection=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=False;"
```

Check for errors with `docker logs containerId`, where `containerId` is the container from `docker ps`.

Comment: try to add also container_name as in my answer

Comment: Still no luck even with the changes you've made

Comment: change the parameter of the password, you probably use a newer version (2017 or newer). Look at my answer

Comment: Update : now while my `db` is initializing, I am getting this : `Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.`

Comment: `7 Login is disabled, and the password is incorrect.` - 

Use the log as I describe in the answer. Are you using Ubuntu under the hood for docker containers?

Comment: I am using git bash in windows with docker desktop

Comment: I am also getting 
`Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: some ip]` in the logs

Comment: I think your "sa" account has been disabled. Try to restart your docker in order to recreate from image

Comment: Well .. now I am getting `Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)`

Comment: Try to apply the `network` changes and append the SQL Server version

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
services:
db:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
  container_name: db
  environment:
    - SA_PASSWORD=Your_password123
    - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "1433:1433"

dotnet_be:
  build: "./"
  ports:
    - "5000:80"
  depends_on:
    - db
```

Note: No double quotes around password, eula and image.
Connection string is thesame

Comment: I haven't managed to get it to work, even with this solution